# Date Picker - Change Selected Date Android

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have used Date Picker and applied max date as 11th Feb, 2020 when today's date is 12th Feb, 2019.

I am having an issue while changing year directly on clicking 'year' on top of date picker.
When date picker is initialized on current date (today's date: 12th Feb, 2019), then if I change year to Feb 2020, date picker shows 12th Feb, 2020 as title but selected day on calendar view is 11th Feb as selected.

See Below images::

img 1 : on date picker initialized as today's date

[image]

img 2 : without changing day, change year

[image]

img 3 : title is 12th feb, 2020 as selected. But as max date is 11th Feb, 2020. 11th is selected on calendar.
Also, on clicking Ok, 12th feb, 2020 is obtained.

[image]

> **I want to remove this selection or just make max date as selected if**
>   **year changes.**

Comment: Zero index based.

Subtract one. Typically this happens on the month as well, although could be something more goofy going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hit and trials, and several google searches, finally found a solution to above:

```
        datePicker.init(currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        currentCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
        new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int selYear, int selMonth,
              int selDay) {
            String dateSelectionType =
                getDateSelectionType(minDate.getTimeInMillis(),
                    maxDate.getTimeInMillis(), selYear, selMonth, selDay);
            if (dateSelectionType.equals("IS_BETWEEN_RANGE")) {
              return;
            }
            if (dateSelectionType.equals("IS_LESS_THAN_MIN")) {
              datePicker.updateDate(minDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), minDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                  minDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

              return;
            }
            if (dateSelectionType.equals("IS_MORE_THAN_MAX")) {
              datePicker.updateDate(maxDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                  maxDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), maxDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
              return;
            }
          }
        });
```

add another method to know if date selected is after max date or before min date ::

```
public static String getDateSelectionType(long minDate, long maxDate,
          int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDayOfMonth) {


Calendar minDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    minDateCalendar.setTimeInMillis(minDate);
    minDateCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    minDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    minDateCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    minDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar maxDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    maxDateCalendar.setTimeInMillis(maxDate);
    maxDateCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    maxDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    maxDateCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    maxDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar selectedDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    selectedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);
    selectedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMonth);
    selectedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDayOfMonth);
    selectedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    selectedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    selectedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    selectedDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if (selectedDateCalendar.getTime().before(minDateCalendar.getTime()))
      return "IS_LESS_THAN_MIN";

    if (selectedDateCalendar.getTime().after(maxDateCalendar.getTime()))
      return "IS_MORE_THAN_MAX";

    return "IS_BETWEEN_RANGE";
  }
```

PS: ***Adding the solution to my own question is just a way out if anyone faces the same issue.***